# Unable to migrate DbContext class in Entity Framework Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am now developing a web api using ASP.NET core web api. This is my first time using ASP.NET core. I was an ASP.NET MVC developer. But been a away for a while. What I am doing now is creating a `DbContext` class for Entity Framework running the migration command. But I am using three different project to separate the logic.

This is my project structure:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I installed following packages.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer  -Projectname thegoodyard.api
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools  -Projectname thegoodyard.api
Install-Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design  -Projectname thegoodyard.api
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer  -Projectname thegoodyard.domain
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools  -Projectname thegoodyard.domain
Install-Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design  -Projectname thegoodyard.domain
```

In the `thegoodyard.domain` project, I created a DB context class called `ThegoodyardContext.cs` with the following definition.

```
namespace thegoodyard.domain.Concrete
{
    public virtual DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    public partial class ThegoodyardContext: DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if(!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=ThegoodyardContext;Trusted_Connection=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
            }
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the `Thegoodyard.api` project, in the `ConfigureServices` method of the `StartUp` class, I registered the context like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddMvc();

     services.AddDbContext<thegoodyard.domain.Concrete.ThegoodyardContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ThegoodyardContext")));
}
```

Then I enabled the migration running the following command

```
enable-migration -projectname thegoodyard.api
```

But it said, the command is too old, use the add-migration instead. I used this instead.

```
add-migration CreateCategory
```

Then I got the following error

> An error occurred while accessing the IWebHost on class 'Program'. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: AddDbContext was called with configuration, but the context type 'ThegoodyardContext' only declares a parameterless constructor. This means that the configuration passed to AddDbContext will never be used. If configuration is passed to AddDbContext, then 'ThegoodyardContext' should declare a constructor that accepts a DbContextOptions and must pass it to the base constructor for DbContext.
>
> No DbContext was found in assembly 'thegoodyard.api'. Ensure that you're using the correct assembly and that the type is neither abstract nor generic.

How can I fix it?

Comment: From the question its really not clear if you are running EF Core or EF 6. For EF6 you use a parameterless constructor, EF Core projects inject `DbContextOptions<T>` in the parameter. The error message clearly states whats wrong, in case you are using EF Core: You did derieve from DbContext and either you only declared a parameterless constructor or you are using EF 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Package manager console

> Default Project : "Select your layer name", like : `thegoodyard.domain`
>   then

`Enable-Migrations`

Please check this link
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-based-migration-in-code-first.aspx